# Difference in creating react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've often seen people using two different ways of making a component

```
import React from 'react';

class Alpha extends React.Component {
  render(){
   ...
  }
}
```

or

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Alpha extends Component {
  render(){
   ...
  }
}
```

which is a better way? and what are the differences in these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which is a better way?

Neither, or both; e.g., it makes no difference.

> and what are the differences in these two methods?

The only difference is that in the second example, there's an in-scope `Component` identifier in the module, and in the first case there isn't. It's very much like you'd written:

```
import React from 'react';
const Component = React.Component;
```

*(Very much like, but not exactly the same, or at least not once true modules are supported by JavaScript engines.)*

It's a matter of style which you use.

Answer (score 0):

the ES6 there is a feature called object Destructuring

{ Component } from 'react' is equal to  react.component 
so they are both the same 
let me

```
let node = {
    type: "Identifier",
    name: "foo"
};

let { type, name } = node;//var type=node.type && var name =node.name


console.log(type);      // "Identifier"
console.log(name);      // "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

They're both the same, I guess the better one is the second one because of it's simplicity.

Basically if your say:

```
import React from 'react';
```

you're importing the "default" exported value from that file:

```
export default function React() {...}
```

But if you're doing:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
```

you are importing the exported value directly.

```
export function Component() {...}
```